# Copy an object (along with bounding box) from one image and paste on different image (only background)

Tags: image-processing, python, object-detection

I have a dataset of images with bounding boxes.
I also have another dataset of images with different backgrounds.

1. I want to copy the images from one dataset (with their ground truth boxes) and paste them on the images of the other dataset with different backgrounds in order to increase my dataset size. 
   Is this possible? 
   So far I have come across algorithms which copy objects (using segmentation masks) from one algorithm to another but since I still don't have the segmentation mask information for my dataset, I can't use these.
2. Is there any method from which we can obtain segmentation masks from bounding boxes?

Comment: I think this is better for SE post, not here.

Comment: Asking for code written to your specification is explicitly off-topic here, and on StackOverflow, it would also lead to a closure for asking for a reference to existing software, libraries or products. So, I'll go ahead and remove that subquestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mask. That's literally what you want to do, only copy the object, not the whole rectangle containing it.

So, you need the info where the object is, and where it's not. That *is* the mask.

So, exactly, you'll need to find that. It's an image segmentation problem. Once you found a mask from the image data, you can use it to selectively copy parts of the original bounding box.

> Is there any method from which we can obtain segmentation masks from bounding boxes?

No. I mean, a bounding box is a rectangle. The same rectangle could contain a witch or a duck, and the rectangle contains zero information on the shape of the object (aside from its maximum extent in two dimensions).

Comment: Thank you. What i get from your answer is that i cannot implement copy-paste with bounding box only and there is no way we can get masks from bounding boxes. Answers my search.

Comment: although if i still want to cut my bounding box(with an object) and paste it on another image, is it possible without generating masks?

Comment: well, if you just want to copy rectangle, do it!